# XML data frame in R

Tags: xml, r

I want to build an R dataset from many XML records that I have (14,000 to be exact).. I can manage to extract values out of each XML file but i do not know how to make a loop to create a data set.

Also when I extract values the column names are

`SA_Data_1$substring` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ConsumerEnquiry>
 <Session>
  <User_ID>ROCK1</User_ID>
  <FullName>ROCK1</FullName>
  <GroupName>014828</GroupName>
  <Subscriber_ID>14828</Subscriber_ID>
  <Group_ID>014828</Group_ID>
  <RequestType>XML2</RequestType>
  <Environment>PRODUCTION</Environment>
  <Version>1.0.0</Version>
 </Session>
</ConsumerEnquiry>
```

So I use:

```
SA_parsed = xmlParse(SA_Data_1$substring)
file3= xmlToList (SA_parsed)
stack(sapply(file3,length))
 v1 = as.matrix(file3$Session)
```

it gives the data set as:

```
V1
1   ROCKLEND1
2   ROCKLEND1
3   014828
4   14828
5   014828
6   XML2
7   PRODUCTION
8   1.0.0
```

so the column names are random 1,2,3 etc.. How can I rename them? and how can I extract 14000 similar records and put them into a data set?

I do not expect a solution but someone who can guide me through the process.. with an overview.. would be great

Comment: I find parsing XML to be complicated effort in trial and error.  If you have not already, I suggest reading: http://www.omegahat.org/RSXML/Tour.pdf  also, you can try xmlSapply to get all.  You may need to nest xml s apply like so: `xmltop <- xmlRoot(xmlTreeParse(URL))` `RawMatrix <- xmlSApply(xmltop[[1]], function(x) xmlSApply(x, xmlValue))`

Comment: Have you tried `xmlToDataFrame(SA_parsed)`? Might work, if the document has a _simple, shallow structure that does appear reasonably commonly_.

Comment: @mgriebe: is RawMatrix <- xmlSApply(xmltop[[1]], function(x) xmlSApply(x, xmlValue)) this like a recursive function in SQL? how does it work?